# What phrases can show up when I type "gg ez" in chat?

Tags: overwatch

In Overwatch, [if a player types "gg ez" into chat](http://www.pcgamer.com/gg-ez-overwatch/), their message will be replaced with one of a few different phrases. These include:

> - Great game, everyone!
> - I'm wrestling with some insecurity issues in my life but thank you for playing with me.
> - I feel very, very small... please hold me...
> - I'm trying to be a nicer person. It's hard, but I'm trying, guys.

**Is there a full list of possible phrases that can show up when typing "gg ez" in chat?**

I tried searching, but the best I could find was an incomplete (and partially incorrect) [list from Neogaf](http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=1265124).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I searched online screenshots and spent about an hour in the training room compiling a single complete list.

Here's every phrase I found along with the relevant screenshot evidence.

> - [Ah shucks... you guys are the best!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laxdF.png)
> - [C’mon, Mom! One more game before you tuck me in. Oops mistell.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtaiD.png)
> - [For glory and honor! Huzzah comrades!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OCi9.png)
> - [Gee whiz! That was fun. Good playing!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laxdF.png)
> - [Good game! Best of luck to you all!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd99Y.jpg)
> - [Great game, everyone!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUaaH.png)
> - [I could really use a hug right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUaaH.png)
> - [I feel very, very small... please hold me...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX8ar.jpg)
> - [I'm trying to be a nicer person. It's hard, but I am trying guys.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxx24.png)
> - [I'm wrestling with some insecurity issues in my life but thank you all for playing with me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZCXg.jpg)
> - [It was an honor to play with you all. Thank you.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtaiD.png)
> - [It’s past my bedtime. Please don’t tell my mommy.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtaiD.png)
> - [Mommy says people my age shouldn’t suck their thumbs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtaiD.png)
> - [Well played. I salute you all.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX8ar.jpg)
> - [Wishing you all the best.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laxdF.png)